# Where should I save authtoken android 2.3

Tags: android, accountmanager

Hi I am learning Android development.
My query is when I get access token from AccountManager Android for "writely" google document. Where should I save the authtoken? I am developing for API 7.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to save it. `AccountManager` caches tokens automatically, so you will get the same token when you call `getAuthToken()`. You should be able to handle the case when the token is expired though. If you really want to save it, SharedPreferences is the natural place.

Comment: Hey Nikolay, I have a similar question about the token that is returned by the call to `GoogleAuthUtils#getToken()`. Should this token be saved in `SharedPreferences` or should you call `getToken()` each time you want to make an authenticated HTTP request? My gut feeling is that there is some caching going on within the call to `getToken()` (and thus, you shouldn't have to store the access token yourself), but I figured it couldn't hurt to confirm with someone who knows what they are talking about. :)

Comment: I don't remember the details, but I *think* it actually makes a HTTP call each time you call `getToken()`. There is no cache database in the Google Play Services app, so unless it has some on-memory cache, there shouldn't be any cache. Watch network traffic when you do two requests in a row to confirm.

Comment: Hm, at least on 4.2 it seems to save the token in the system `accounts.db`, so it is effectively cached the same way as the AccountManager does. It might work differently on 2.x.

Comment: Looking into this a bit further, Google Play Services runs in the same process as the AccountManager Google authentication module, so it can use the AccountManager database to cache tokens. Haven't tested it, but most likely it works the same one all platforms: uses `setPassword()` and `setExtras()` to cache tokens and token metadata in `accounts.db`.

Comment: Ahh... wish they had documented this in a little more detail somewhere. I'll try it out on 2.x and report back if there are any weird differences. Thanks!

Comment: @codingcrow I don't believe there were any differences.